# How to hold the value of a variable inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have variable `myinterval` inside `functional component` with **Hooks**, and I update and asign **new value** this `myinterval`, just inside `useEffect`.

But after a state gets update `myinterval` holds the prev value, I mean the value which I initilized inside functional components.

```
function App(props) {

  const [name, setName] = useState('Muhammad');

  let myinterval = null;

  useEffect(()=>{

    myinterval = setInterval(()=> {}, 100);

  }, []);

  const print = async () => {
    setName('new name');
     console.log(myinterval);
  };

  return <button className="App" onClick={print}>hey</button>;
}
```

Now as you can see when I click `print` **function**, the first time it is not null, but in second time it is null.

This is because of `setName('new name');`, actually after `setName('new name');` called, then `myinterval` return null value.

**What I want?**

I want `myinterval` variable should return always the value which re-initialized inside `useEffect`.

As per my need, I can't declare my `myinterval` variable outside of `function App(props){}`.

*Here is an example I shown it very simple.*
[Simple Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-1gd1g)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will set the interval only on first render and cancel it on unmount

```
useEffect(()=>{
    myInterval = setInterval(()=> {}, 100);
    return () => clearInterval(myInterval)
  }, []);
}
```

If you want to store a reference to the interval id, you should not use a plain variable (which is set at each render), but rather use a React ref with the useRef hook

```
function App(props) {

  const [name, setName] = useState('Muhammad');

  const myInterval = useRef(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    myInterval.current = setInterval(()=> {}, 100);
    return () => {
      if (myInterval.current) { 
        clearInterval(myInterval.current)
        myInterval.current = null
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const print = async () => {
    setName('new name');
     console.log(myInterval.current);
  };

  return <button className="App" onClick={print}>hey</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let myinterval = null;
```

runs every time, on every render

```
useEffect(()=>{
    myinterval = setInterval(()=> {}, 100);
}, []);
```

runs only at mount, leaving `myinterval` with a `null` value

Fix for what you want to achieve:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Muhammad");
  const [timeout, setTimeout] = useState("init value");

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setTimeout("new value"), 3000);
  }, []);

  const print = async () => {
    setName("setting name");
    console.log(timeout);
  };

  return (
    <button className="App" onClick={print}>
      hey
    </button>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```